# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'securityService'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

> SecurityConfig

```
package com.book.entity.security.impl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**", "/", "/myAccount" };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().
        /* antMatchers("/**"). */
                antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                .deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll().and().rememberMe();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(securityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

> SecurityUtility

```
package com.book.entity.security.impl;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SecurityUtility {
    private static final String SALT = "salt"; // Salt should be protected carefully

    @Bean
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }

    @Bean
    public static String randomPassword() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (salt.length() < 18) {
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String saltStr = salt.toString();
        return saltStr;
    }
}
```

> UserRepository

```
package com.book.entity.security.impl;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.book.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByUsername(String userName);
}
```

> SecurityService

```
package com.book.entity.security.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.book.entity.User;

@Service
public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);

        if (null == user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

> Error:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'securityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.book.entity.User com.book.entity.security.impl.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [username] on this ManagedType [com.book.entity.User]

Comment: The exception tells you what is wrong. `Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [username] on this ManagedType [com.book.entity.User]`. Your `User` doesn't have a `username` field.

Comment: how I can i fix it sir ?

Comment: thanks sir,,,i rename the field of userName to username...but i rellay do not know why happed it. please explain.

Comment: What isn't clear about the exception.  Your field was named `userName` not `username`. The latter was expected because you named the method `findByUsername`.